# What basic linux command-line utility can I use to test a JDBC connection?

Tags: linux, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm troubleshooting an issue with importing data to Apache Solr from a MS SQL Server database via a JDBC connection.  Solr is hosted on a CentOS linux machine, and SQL Server is (of course) on a seperate Windows Server box.

I can see the login attempt on SQL Server, but it stops at a single `Audit Login` event, and Solr never completes the query, and never throws an exception.  The same SQL user works fine when connecting directly; leading me to suspect either a network issue or (possibly) a SQL configuration issue.  What's more, the production Solr box successfully queries the QA database.

What basic CLI utility can I run from the Solr/Linux box to connect to SQL Server, using the same JDBC driver and parameters, to test if I'm able to perform basic SQL queries?

Comment: In actual answer to a cmdline tool, my searches came up with sqlline

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)  or [DBVis](http://www.dbvis.com/) both are Java based and need a JDBC driver, so you can use the same one.  Great tools.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot to specify that this is a command-line only server, but I'll see if by chance I can run it remotely over xming